# hadoop cannot connect to localhost

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I am a beginner in hadoop. Now, I have a maven project and the configuration is as following:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "http://127.0.0.1:8088");
conf.set("yarn.resourcemanager.address", "http://127.0.0.1:50070");
conf.set("mapreduce.framework.name", "yarn");
```

But when I run it on my laptop, the program will stop at

```
INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /127.0.0.1:50070
```

If I change the configuration to

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "http://localhost:8088");
conf.set("yarn.resourcemanager.address", "http://hoathost:50070");
conf.set("mapreduce.framework.name", "yarn");
```

The program will stop at

```
INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at localhost/127.0.0.1:50070
```

I can see the 127.0.0.1:50070 page in my browser so Hadoop should be started successfully.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

50070 is HDFS Namenode webui port, Default yarn.resourcemanager.address IPC port is 8032, Try to update the below line in the code.

conf.set("yarn.resourcemanager.address", "http://127.0.0.1:8032");

Answer (score 0):

If you have your cluster running fine, the simplest way to connect this cluster can be

1. Copy hadoop conf from $HADOOP_CONF_DIR to a local dir
2. Load the configuration files to your client `Configuration`

> Configuration conf = new Configuration();
>
> conf.addResource(new Path("file:///path/to/client/yarn-site.xml"));
>
> ...

if you are using HDP or CDH distribution, you should be able to download client config package and use them locally to connect to a cluster.